# one message getting consumed by 2 consumer

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have configured two consumers which is subscribed to a topic. Now when i have a message on the topic both the consumers are consuming the same message. I am not deleting the message until i get a ack from some process so that i am not losing out on any message.

What i intend to do is when i have 2 messages each consumer should be individually working on the message for ex first consumer on first message and second consumer on second message.

I have written all my code(producers,consumers) in java (no frame works like spring maven etc are used.)

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

`Topic` publishes messages to be consumed by multiple consumers whereas `Queue` publishes messages to be consumed by only one consumer. So i believe you need to use `Queue` instead of `Topic`.

Read more about Topic and Queue differences:

http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html

Comment: I have understand diff between topic and queue, If I have single producer which is sending say two messages at a time to activemq queue. How can I do parallel processing of two messages by two consumers? **Note:** I can't have two diff queues because then I would need two producers.

Comment: If you have multiple consumers running in their own threads then multiple messages can be picked by consumers and processed at a time.